# Is left outer join equivalent to inner join for non-null foreign keys?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, left-join

Each city has owning country:

```
create table COUNTRY 
(
     ID number not null,
     NAME varchar,
     primary key (ID)
);

create table CITY 
(
     ID number not null,
     NAME varchar,
     COUNTRY_ID number not null,
     primary key (ID)
);

alter table CITY 
    add constraint CITY_COUNTRY_FK
        foreign key (COUNTRY_ID) references COUNTRY (ID);
```

Is the following:

```
select * 
from CITY c
left outer join COUNTRY ctr on ctr.ID = c.COUNTRY_ID
where ...;
```

equivalent to:

```
select * 
from CITY c
inner join COUNTRY ctr on ctr.ID = c.COUNTRY_ID
where ...;
```

because COUNTRY_ID is `foreign key` and `not null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the `left join` is redundant based on the data model.  The `NOT NULL` constraint means that every city has a `country_id`.  The foreign key constraint means that the `country_id`s are valid and are in the `country` table.

Combined, these constraints say that every row in `city` has a matching row in `country`.  When all keys match, the `left join` is equivalent to `inner join`.

Comment: This right here might be the single most useful so answer to date for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes basically if you are sure all entries had an equivalent, at all cases the left will be equivalent to inner.

As you mentioned each city has owning country, so yes it's gonna be the same result